# Why OpenMP invoking 2 threads to each print one line, but end up printing 3 lines

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

In this program, I invoke two threads to add a random number to `sum`, and the first thread to make sum > 1000 is the winner.

```cpp
#include <omp.h>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    ofstream outFileForTask;
    outFileForTask.open("task_output.txt", std::ios_base::app);
    time_t currentTime;
    time(&currentTime);
    outFileForTask << "\n\nTestTime: " << ctime(&currentTime);

    std::mt19937 randomNumGenerator(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> uniformDist(-50, 100);
    int sum = 0;
    int terminatingSum = 1000;
    int winnerThreadId = -1;
    int round = 0;
    while (winnerThreadId == -1) {
        round++;
#pragma omp parallel num_threads(2) shared(sum)
        {
            int randomNum = uniformDist(randomNumGenerator);
            int threadNum = omp_get_thread_num();
            int prevSum;
#pragma omp atomic capture
            {
                prevSum = sum;
                sum += randomNum;
            }
            if (prevSum <= terminatingSum && prevSum + randomNum > terminatingSum) {
                winnerThreadId = threadNum;
            }
            outFileForTask << "Round: " << round
                            << "Thread Id：" << threadNum
                            << " added: " << randomNum
                            << " to sum, and new sum is ：" << prevSum + randomNum
                            << endl;
        }
    }

    outFileForTask << "Winner is thread: " << winnerThreadId <<
                    endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But the result I get is:

I wonder why in each round, thread 0 prints two identical lines. In fact, in each parallel block there is only one print statement, and two worker threads to execute the parallel block, so there should be two lines per round.

```bash
TestTime: Wed Oct 19 16:59:15 2022
Round: Round: 11hread Id： 0 added: -30� added: -30 to sum, and new sum is ：-60


TestTime: Wed Oct 19 16:59:15 2022
Round: Round: 11hread Id： 0 added: -30� added: -30 to sum, and new sum is ：-60

Round: 2Thread Id：0 added: 60Round: , and new sum is ：0Id： 2Round: 2Thread Id：0 added: 60Round: , and new sum is ：0Id： 2Thread Id：1 added: -19 to sum, and new sum is ：-19
Round: 3Thread Id：0 added: 24 to sum, and new sum is ：5
Round: 3Thread Id：0 added: 24 to sum, and new sum is ：5
Round: 3Thread Id：1 added: -13 to sum, and new sum is ：-8
Round: 4Thread Id：0 added: -49 to sum, and new sum is ：-57
Round: 4Thread Id：0 added: -49 to sum, and new sum is ：-57
Round: 4Thread Id：1 added: 34 to sum, and new sum is ：-23
Round: 5Thread Id：0 added: 56 to sum, and new sum is ：33
Round: 5Thread Id：0 added: 56 to sum, and new sum is ：33
Round: 5Thread Id：1 added: 52 to sum, and new sum is ：85
Round: 6Thread Id：0 added: 35 to sum, and new sum is ：120
Round: 6Thread Id：0 added: 35 to sum, and new sum is ：120
Round: 6Thread Id：1 added: 4 to sum, and new sum is ：124
Round: 7Thread Id：0 added: 21 to sum, and new sum is ：145
Round: 7Thread Id：0 added: 21 to sum, and new sum is ：145
Round: 7Thread Id：1 added: 44 to sum, and new sum is ：189
Round: 8Thread Id：0 added: 62 to sum, and new sum is ：251
Round: 8Thread Id：0 added: 62 to sum, and new sum is ：251
Round: 8Thread Id：1 added: -29 to sum, and new sum is ：222
Round: 9Thread Id：0 added: -2 to sum, and new sum is ：220
Round: 9Thread Id：0 added: -2 to sum, and new sum is ：220
Round: 9Thread Id：1 added: 20 to sum, and new sum is ：240
Round: 10Thread Id：0 added: 3 to sum, and new sum is ：243
Round: 10Thread Id：0 added: 3 to sum, and new sum is ：243
Round: 10Thread Id：1 added: 20 to sum, and new sum is ：263
Round: 11Thread Id：0 added: 27 to sum, and new sum is ：290
Round: 11Thread Id：0 added: 27 to sum, and new sum is ：290
Round: 11Thread Id：1 added: 52 to sum, and new sum is ：342
Round: 12Thread Id：0 added: -18 to sum, and new sum is ：324
Round: 12Thread Id：0 added: -18 to sum, and new sum is ：324
Round: 12Thread Id：1 added: -9 to sum, and new sum is ：315
Round: 13Thread Id：0 added: 49 to sum, and new sum is ：364
Round: 13Thread Id：0 added: 49 to sum, and new sum is ：364
Round: 13Thread Id：1 added: 43 to sum, and new sum is ：407
Round: 14Thread Id：0 added: -27 to sum, and new sum is ：380
Round: 14Thread Id：0 added: -27 to sum, and new sum is ：380
Round: 14Thread Id：1 added: 24 to sum, and new sum is ：404
Round: 15Thread Id：0 added: 68 to sum, and new sum is ：472
Round: 15Thread Id：0 added: 68 to sum, and new sum is ：472
Round: 15Thread Id：1 added: 27 to sum, and new sum is ：499
Round: 16Thread Id：0 added: 76 to sum, and new sum is ：575
Round: 16Thread Id：0 added: 76 to sum, and new sum is ：575
Round: 16Thread Id：1 added: 91 to sum, and new sum is ：666
Round: 17Thread Id：0 added: -4 to sum, and new sum is ：662
Round: 17Thread Id：0 added: -4 to sum, and new sum is ：662
Round: 17Thread Id：1 added: -19 to sum, and new sum is ：643
Round: 18Thread Id：0 added: -47 to sum, and new sum is ：596
Round: 18Thread Id：0 added: -47 to sum, and new sum is ：596
Round: 18Thread Id：1 added: -28 to sum, and new sum is ：568
Round: 19Thread Id：0 added: 43 to sum, and new sum is ：611
Round: 19Thread Id：0 added: 43 to sum, and new sum is ：611
Round: 19Thread Id：1 added: -9 to sum, and new sum is ：602
Round: 20Thread Id：0 added: 33 to sum, and new sum is ：635
Round: 20Thread Id：0 added: 33 to sum, and new sum is ：635
Round: 20Thread Id：1 added: 29 to sum, and new sum is ：664
Round: 21Thread Id：0 added: -29 to sum, and new sum is ：635
Round: 21Thread Id：0 added: -29 to sum, and new sum is ：635
Round: 21Thread Id：1 added: 28 to sum, and new sum is ：663
Round: 22Thread Id：0 added: 25 to sum, and new sum is ：688
Round: 22Thread Id：0 added: 25 to sum, and new sum is ：688
Round: 22Thread Id：1 added: -23 to sum, and new sum is ：665
Round: 23Thread Id：0 added: 11 to sum, and new sum is ：676
Round: 23Thread Id：0 added: 11 to sum, and new sum is ：676
Round: 23Thread Id：1 added: 55 to sum, and new sum is ：731
Round: 24Thread Id：0 added: -49 to sum, and new sum is ：682
Round: 24Thread Id：0 added: -49 to sum, and new sum is ：682
Round: 24Thread Id：1 added: 22 to sum, and new sum is ：704
Round: 25Thread Id：0 added: 49 to sum, and new sum is ：753
Round: 25Thread Id：0 added: 49 to sum, and new sum is ：753
Round: 25Thread Id：1 added: 14 to sum, and new sum is ：767
Round: 26Thread Id：0 added: 61 to sum, and new sum is ：828
Round: 26Thread Id：0 added: 61 to sum, and new sum is ：828
Round: 26Thread Id：1 added: 29 to sum, and new sum is ：857
Round: 27Thread Id：0 added: -16 to sum, and new sum is ：841
Round: 27Thread Id：0 added: -16 to sum, and new sum is ：841
Round: 27Thread Id：1 added: -18 to sum, and new sum is ：823
Round: 28Thread Id：0 added: 98 to sum, and new sum is ：921
Round: 28Thread Id：0 added: 98 to sum, and new sum is ：921
Round: 28Thread Id：1 added: 21 to sum, and new sum is ：942
Round: 29Thread Id：0 added: 13 to sum, and new sum is ：955
Round: 29Thread Id：0 added: 13 to sum, and new sum is ：955
Round: 29Thread Id：1 added: 28 to sum, and new sum is ：983
Round: 30Thread Id：0 added: 74 to sum, and new sum is ：1057
Round: 30Thread Id：0 added: 74 to sum, and new sum is ：1057
Round: 30Thread Id：1 added: -14 to sum, and new sum is ：1043
Winner is thread: 0
```

Comment: It looks like you run two processes so the main is called twice. Don't you use MPI or something like this? Besides, you need a critical section for the thread to print lines correctly. `#pragma omp critical` can do that. Alternatively `printf` should do that for you assuming only one call is done.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Could you explain "run two processes so the main is called twice" in more detail? I think OpenMP would create one slave thread and there is already one master thread when I specified `num_threads(2)`. They both execute the `{}` wrapped block once.

Comment: OpenMP is initially based on the fork-join paradigm so it creates thread only in parallel section (though threads may last longer in practice). In practice you should see 2 OpenMP threads (1 master + 1 worker).  The thing is `TestTime` is printed twice while it is outside the OpenMP section so I think the main is called twice. Thus, the process is certainly created twice. This should have nothing to do with OpenMP.

Comment: @JérômeRichard This is how I compile and run the program: `g++ -fopenmp -o main main.cpp && ./main`. I've tested this on both OpenMP 2015 and 2018 multiple times. Seems the error always occurs. But from the compile and run command nothing seems wrong. What could have called main twice? Seems to be an OpenMP bug?

Comment: I've compiled and run your code, and the output is just a mess... I have twice `TestTime` printed like in your output, but the prints in the parallel section are completely blended. I have then added a `critical` pragma for the prints and everything is correct now: each thread prints only one line at each round, and  `TestTime`  is printed only once. I can't really explain what happens, I suspect that writing to the same file is not thread safe and can result in undefined behaviors.

Comment: Thread safety when accessing the same file has never been clear to me... in doubt I always put the IOs in critical sections.

Comment: @PierU I also tried the `critical` pragma and omp locks. Both produced correct result. So probably the issue has something to do with `fstream`.

Comment: @PierU I just tried using `printf` instead of `fstream` (`printf` is thread-safe), and the result is correct (no more multiple TestTime or identical line issue). So I guessed this confirmed that the problem comes from `fstream`.

Comment: I highly doubt this could be an OpenMP bug since OpenMP should not even be initialised when the print is done. Certainly a running issue or a bug in the program. I advise you to make the program simpler until the print is not done twice. Btw, writting in cout is not thread safe as previously said.

Comment: @JérômeRichard I think the `TestTime` print statement is not executed twice (OpenMP is not initialized when printing `TestTime`). It maybe just an undefined behavior of `fstream` running in parallel. I guess when I used `outFileForTask` later in the program it somehow repeatedly printed(actually more precisely 'wrote' to file because it is `fstream`, print for simplicity) what it has already printed a while ago. Why I say so? Because if I use `printf `, even if I do not add `critical` or locks to synchronize all the print statements, nothing goes wrong. The twice `TestTime` problem goes away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `#pragma omp critical` before the prints in the parallel region not only avoids blending the output, it also removes all duplicate prints. Writing to the same output file seems to not be thread-safe in this context and results in undefined behavior.

EDIT (copying the latest comment of the OP, which tend to confirm the thread-safety issue):

> I just tried using `printf` instead of `fstream` (`printf` is thread-safe), and the result is correct (no more multiple `TestTime` or identical line issue). So I guessed this confirmed that the problem comes from `fstream`

Comment: From the start I know `fstream` is not thread-safe, but I assumed using thread-unsafe file operation only leads to blended output, but not duplicate output. So this is really strange undefined behavior. It is a lesson: do not assume undefined behavior.